# Open link in new tab with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a link in a new tab. HTML tag for the link is

```
    <a id="target_link" target="_blank" href="http://yahoo.com">
```

But it's not working according to my expectations. I want to open in new tab after a while. Below is the snippet of jquery which is working perfectly fine but not opening in a new tab

```
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        window.location = $('target_link').get('href');
    },1800);
```

Comment: [Window.location()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location): *...current location of the document...* [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open): *Loads a resource into either a new browsing context (such as a window) or one that already exists...* ==> **The proposed answers should work just fine..**

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.open($('#target_link').attr('href'), '_blank');
}, 1800);
```

Comment: Assuming popups aren't disabled (which is highly likely)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.open('https://support.wwf.org.uk', '_blank');
    },1800)
```

Try this
**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ph52bv6/)**

Comment: This  way it is being blocked by chrome as a pop-up blocked. Is there a way to prevent this. Like it automatically opens it in a new window.

Comment: @MuhammadHussainRana No, because popups are considered terrible UX (user experience) and most modern browsers have given users the privilege to disable them by default until they decided to explicitly allow them on sites they trust.